# matplotlib.pyplot is not working!

Tags: 14.04, anaconda, ipython, jupyter, matplotlib

I'm using Jupyter Notebook, and matplotlib.pyplot is not working. I'm using Python 2.7 in Ubuntu 14.04.

[image: Image of the error message]

Answer (score 6):

Your code got the following error message:

```
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Change your Python code like this and then test it first in the terminal:

```py
:~$ python
>>> import numpy
>>> from numpy import core
>>> from numpy.core import multiarray as ma
```

If you also have python-matplotlib installed, the first line of code to enable plotting in the current Jupyter Notebook is `%matplotlib inline`

Your Jupyter Notebook also shows another error message:

```
RuntimeError: module compile against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9
```

numpy from Anaconda is not compatible with ipython or some other package that you have installed. This would not happen if you installed the python-numpy, ipython, and python-matplotlib packages from the default Ubuntu repositories. I have installed Jupyter Notebook in Ubuntu 14.04 with the command `sudo apt-get -y install ipython ipython-notebook && pip install --user jupyter` and used it with ipython, python-matplotlib and python-numpy also from the default Ubuntu repositories without any problems.

To install jupyter-notebook in Ubuntu 18.04-19.10 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-all python3-pip python3-notebook jupyter jupyter-core python-ipykernel
```

To install jupyter-notebook in Ubuntu 20.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-all python3-pip jupyter-notebook jupyter
```

Comment: The reason why I wrote my code in 3 steps is so you could test if numpy works. The same code works in my computer, so you probably have something wrong in your Ananconda installation.

Comment: @karel I think the first line in the error messages is the clue here, `RuntimeErrror module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9`.